# JavaScript - Multiple signals received after click

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a webapp using jQueryMobile. When I'm using the app and I click a button it runs the script multiple times.

*For example:*

I have a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="login-normal" value="Login" />
```

And I have this JavaScript for debugging on which this error occurs:

```
$("input#login-normal").live('click',function() {
     console.log("Test");
});
```

On the very first click it works (and it goes to another screen for example), but when I go back to that screen and I click again, it outputs multiple console.logs

- edit

this is the exact code as in my .js file.

```
$("div#login input#login-normal").live('click',function() { 
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var password = $("input#password").val();

    user.checkUser(email, password, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#home", { transition: "slidedown"});
        } else {
            console.log("Wrong email or password.");
        }
    });
    console.log("Login");
});
```

user.checkUser is an object from my class User which checks if the user exists in the database (WebSQL). returns true of false on callback.

Comment: It sounds like you might be re-binding the event handler over and over. Can you share more code? Also, `.live` is to no longer be used. Use `.on` instead.

Comment: see my posts for the edit / .on doesn't fix my issue

Comment: @AngeloA Is the code in your edit run in the global scope or is it wrapped in any other code?

Comment: it is wrapped in $(document).bind('pageinit', function(event) { // code here });

Comment: Thank you Sheikh Heera. That worked for me.

Comment: @AngeloA, answered it and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `on` instead of `live` and try it like

```
$("input#login-normal").off('click').on('click',function() {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.mobile.activePage.find("div#login input#login-normal").live('click',function() {...}
```

If that still fires multiple times you can try

```
$(document).delegate("[data-role=page]", "pagebeforeshow", function () {                
        $("div#login input#login-normal").bind("click", function (e) {...}
}
```